# Why Recursive method prints numbers backwards

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

Why is recursion backwards when I call the function before printing but not if I print after calling the function?

For some reason I don't understand why the recursive method prints backward when it's the function is being called before the print and why is it not backward when I print before calling the function.

Could someone explain it to me?

```
public void tricky1(int n) {
    if (n >= 0) {
        System.out.print(n);
        tricky1(n - 2);
     }
}
```

Second

```
public void tricky2(int n) {
    if (n >= 0) {
        tricky2(n - 2);
        System.out.print(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs (`https://ericlippert.com/`)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

When you run this code

```
tricky2(n - 2);
System.out.print(n);
```

The result is being printed in ascending order because statement `System.out.print(n);` is being executed after the very last recursive call in the branch of execution created by the line `tricky2(n- 2);`.

Conversely, when this snippet is being executed.

```
System.out.print(n);
tricky2(n - 2);
```

The number will be printed on the console before the recursive call. Therefore, numbers will get printed in the descending order (from highest to lowest).